# Model predict with tensorflow 2.0 causes python kernel to die and restart

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I ported my model from tensorflow 1.15 to 2.0 by simply using tf.keras instead of keras. 
The model works fine under tf 1.15 even with GPU, but in case of tf 2.0 or 2.1 when I call mode.predict() it causes python kernel to die and restart. There is no error message at all. With tensorflow 2.1 the phenomenon is the same.

The model creation works fine, so the model is compiled, weights are loaded from a file. The problem is caused by calling model.predict().

Any hint?

```
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/"
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, Conv1D, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Activation, LeakyReLU, add, Subtract
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Input, Concatenate, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, Nadam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import RandomNormal
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
def residual_layer( input_block, filters, kernel_size, use_bias=True, use_reg = True,
                reg_const = 0.0001):

    x = input_block
    if use_reg:
        x = Conv2D(
            filters=filters
            , kernel_size=kernel_size
            , data_format="channels_first"
            , padding='same'
            , use_bias=use_bias
            , activation='linear'
            , kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg_const)
        )(x)
    else:
        x = Conv2D(
            filters=filters
            , kernel_size=kernel_size
            , data_format="channels_first"
            , padding='same'
            , use_bias=use_bias
            , activation='linear'
        )(x)

    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    #x = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(x)

    x = add([input_block, x])

    x = LeakyReLU()(x)

    return (x)


def conv_layer( x, filters, kernel_size, padding='same', use_bias=True, use_reg = True,
                reg_const = 0.0001, use_batchnorm = True, use_LeakyReLU = True):
    if use_reg:
        x = Conv2D(
            filters=filters
            , kernel_size=kernel_size
            , data_format="channels_first"
            , padding=padding
            , use_bias=use_bias
            , activation='relu'
            , kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg_const)
        )(x)
    else:
        x = Conv2D(
            filters=filters
            , kernel_size=kernel_size
            , data_format="channels_first"
            , padding=padding
            , use_bias=use_bias
            , activation='relu'
        )(x)
    if use_batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(x)
    if use_LeakyReLU:
        x = LeakyReLU()(x)

    return (x)


def LeakyReLU_layer(x):
    x = LeakyReLU()(x)

    return (x)

def value_head(x, use_bias = True, use_reg = True,
                reg_const = 0.0001, use_batchnorm = True, use_LeakyReLU = True):
    if use_reg:
        x = Conv2D(
            filters=1
            , kernel_size=(1, 1)
            , data_format="channels_first"
            , padding='same'
            , use_bias=use_bias
            , activation='linear'
            , kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg_const)
        )(x)
    else:
        x = Conv2D(
            filters=1
            , kernel_size=(1, 1)
            , data_format="channels_first"
            , padding='same'
            , use_bias=use_bias
            , activation='linear'
        )(x)

    if use_batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(x)
    if use_LeakyReLU:
        x = LeakyReLU()(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)

    x = Dense(
        29*29*2
        , use_bias=use_bias
        , activation='relu'
        , kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg_const)
    )(x)
    if use_LeakyReLU:
        x = LeakyReLU()(x)

    x = Dense(
        1
        , use_bias=use_bias
        , activation='tanh'
        , kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(reg_const)
        , name='value_head'
    )(x)

    return (x)


def build_model_v01_only_value(weightsFileName = None):

    main_input = Input(shape=(3,19,19,), name='main_input')


    x = conv_layer(main_input, 64, (5,5), padding='same')
    x = conv_layer(x, 64, (3, 3), padding='same')
    x = conv_layer(x, 64, (3, 3), padding='same')
    x = conv_layer(x, 64, (3, 3), padding='same')


    for h in range(5):
        x = residual_layer(x, 64, (3,3))

    vh = value_head(x)

    modelv = Model(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[vh])

    modelv.compile(loss={'value_head': 'mean_squared_error'},
                  optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['mae'])



    plot_model(modelv, 'gb_modelv_01.png', show_shapes=True)

    if weightsFileName != None:
        modelv.load_weights(weightsFileName)

    return modelv


vm = build_model_v01_only_value("memoryweights/vm_0018.hdf5")

Xin= np.zeros((noOfMirrorsForEval+1, 3, 19, 19), dtype=float)
# ... some calculation of Xin
v_predict = vm.predict(Xin).flatten()
```

Comment: Have you tried `model.evaluate()` ?

Comment: I tried it now, model.evaluate() causes the same problem (kernel restart)

Comment: can you check using `nvidia-smi` to see if the process is still running on the GPU or running out of memory.

Comment: Also I would recommend reinstalling your tensorflow or creating a new environment for the upgraded tensorflow.

Comment: Hi, this environment does not use GPU, tensorflow_gpu is not installed (but the CPU version). Thus there is is no sense to run the nvidia-smi command. At start of the program, during tensorflow import it initializes the Intel MKL. This is shown among the console messages - so I suppose it tries to run parallel processes, but no sign of any activity in this regard (PIDs are not listed) when I tried to run model.predict().  As to your last comment, this is a totally new environment, freshly installed just for this purpose....

Comment: Can you please try passing a smaller batch of input to the predict function. It's likely that the entire test set as a single batch is too huge and large for the memory.

Comment: Hi, this is not the problem for sure, since the test set shape is of (4, 3, 19, 19), so it is very small.

Comment: I tried to run the program on different versions of python, mkl and tensorflow. Please don't forget that this program runs with no error on tensorflow 1.14, 1.15. When running it on python 3.7 and tensorflow 2.1, I get the following error: ... \lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnimplementedError:  The Conv2D op currently only supports the NHWC tensor format on the CPU. The op was given the format: NCHW
  [[node model/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-8-bdd529526964>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1937].  Any idea what could be the problem?